# Using String.Split() and Contains() in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, jquery-autocomplete

I've made an autocomplete box, that shows the list of items according to the user input in TextBox, the following method is invoked each time when user types a char in textbox and then it returns the list of items with matched words:

```
internal readonly ObjectSet<T> _set; //database data
public IEnumerable<IOrganization> GetOrganizations(string Input, int max)
{
    return this._set.Where(e.name.Contains(Input)).Take(max).ToList();

}
```

the database data looks like a catalog with names of organizations:

```
name
------
Organization #20
Clinic of some type #22
another clinic bla bla
```

etc.

Everything works fine. But now I would like to return the list of items where `name` contains each word user types in.
For example, if my `name` looks like: `Republic organization #23`
and user types in: `repu org`
this name should be in the returned list.
I guess i should split user input into array of words and then check for `Contains()` each word:

```
string[] terms = input.Split(' ');
```

how can I then check for each item in `terms` at one time, so that my `name` would contain all words from the input? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by nesting an `All` predicate (that iterates over your `terms` collection) within your `Where` predicate (that iterates over your `_set`):

```
return this._set.Where(e => terms.All(t => e.name.Contains(t)));
```

More concisely:

```
return this._set.Where(e => terms.All(e.name.Contains));
```

Answer (score 0):

The answered code gave me error, so this worked for me

`terms.Contains(e.name) || e.name.Contains(terms)`

I think my error was because "terms" in my case was a RadTextBox
This was my error

`Failure: Execution of 'System.Linq.Enumerable:All(IEnumerable1,Func2)' on the database server side currently not implemented`